# CHS Error installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu, so I boot from a pen-drive where I installed the ISO, I select `Install Ubuntu` and [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htQhp.jpg) appears in the screen (OCRed):

```
CHS: Error aa01 reading sector 2980399 (185/165/28)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 2982447
CHS: Error aa01 reading sector 2982320 (185/195/59)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 2984360
CHS: Error aa01 reading sector 2984368 (185/228/28)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 2986416
CHS: Error aa01 reading sector 2986416 (186/5/60)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 2988464
CHs: Error aa01 reading sector 2988464 (186/38/29)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 2990512
CHS: Error aa01 reading sector 2990512 (186/70/61)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 2992560
CHS: Error aa01 reading sector 2992560 (186/103/30)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 2994608
CHS: Error aa01 reading sector 2994608 (186/135/62)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 2996656
CHS: Error aa01 reading sector 3677 (0/90/56)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 5725
CHS: Error aa01 reading sector 2908096 (181/37/49)
EDD: Error aa00 reading sector 2910144
```

Is there a problem with my pen-drive?

PS: Sorry for the broken english, It's not my mother language.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Did you verify the ISO was valid; refer https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 for some clues, but yes it looks to me like you have a problem with your image on the pen-drive.  Either download failed; your write to the pen-drive failed  (which could mean the pen-drive itself is faulty, or just bad luck and bad-write).   I would suggest verifying your ISO image, then try a re-write (to the same, or another pen-drive).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)